# Time on y axis - Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have plotted a figure with imagesc. The data was extracted from a file and the time was readed as a string column so I converted to double with datenum.

```
  time = datenum(time, 'HH:MM:SS');

  figure(1)
  imagesc(freq,time,rssimat);
  colorbar;
```

In this way it works but the picture looks like this

[image]

As you notice the y axis has this double numbers which represent the time converted with datenum. I actually would like to see my actual time like 'HH:MM:SS'.
Therefore I added a line:

```
  datetick('y', 'HH:MM:SS');
```

And now my figure looks like...
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you need to "zoom in" on Y axis. Your tracked interval appears to be very short in duration while on the Y axis you display the whole day.

Did you try: `datetick('y', 'HH:MM:SS', 'keeplimits');` ? This will basically zoom in and fill the entire chart, while on the Y axis you will have *HH:MM:SS* format.

If you use `datetick('y', 'HH:MM:SS', 'keepticks');` it will preserve the locations of the ticks while converting the labels to *HH:MM:SS* format.

Comment: yep thanks, but then it is showing only the time between 14:20 and 14:21 which is in fact that line there...

Comment: @ayasha Then i have misunderstood your question. Isn't this what you wanted? If you want to display 24 hours, you need sufficient data to cover a 24h run. Can you add more clarification?

Comment: i do have data to cover 24 hours!

Comment: See my edited post. Try with 'keepticks'. If it won't work, could you add some input data samples in your input file?

Answer (score -1):

u can use `ylim` function in matlab to limit your y-ranges